# KRL twitter search & app/entity variables available to all rules? (global)

Tags: dataset, global-variables, krl

I am wanting to build a Kynetx app that does a datasource query once and is available to all my rules in my ruleset/app. It would also be nice to do the same for app and entity variables. I'm not sure how to go about doing this and need some help. Do I write a rule that does the queries and then spits it out to the rest of the rules in some special way?

Comment: Do I even have to hire Jon Skeet? I bet if I channel enough of my inner Jon Skeetness, he will telepathically hear what I am trying to do and the mere thought of Jon starting to think about it would probably fix it. : )

Comment: Ah, but you assume 100% of his brainpower would be there. No, there's 25% on solving world hunger with C#, 25% on writing the C# spec for 2020. And so on. You get like 1%. It's a tough call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `datasource` (and `dataset`) queries in the `global` block of your application, and these variables will be available application wide.

```
global {
  datasource mydatasource <- "http://example.com/path/to/datasource";
  args = {"myvar":"myvalue"};
  results = datasource:mydatasource(args);
}
```

Keep in mind that this call is made in your global block, so you only have variables available in the global block. If your datasource depends on variables in a rule, you will to make the datasource query there.